# How to get a username from asp:login to store in a session?

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication

I'm using a simple asp:login form for user authentication on my site.  I've set it up as basic as I can, and my code looks like this:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginForm" runat="server"
    DestinationPageUrl="~/LoggedIn/TaskPanel.aspx" >
</asp:Login>
```

Appropriate tables are in my SQL Server Database and login works like a charm :)

Once logged in, I want to retrieve some user data and store it in session for later use.  To do this, I intend on passing the username through a Stored Procedure in my database.
I have tried the following but now when I try to authenticate, nothing happens & the page refreshes.

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginForm" runat="server"
    DestinationPageUrl="~/LoggedIn/TaskPanel.aspx"
    OnAuthenticate="storeUserDetails" >
</asp:Login>
```

C#:

```
protected void storeUserDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["accountCustUsername"] = LoginForm.UserName;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I have also tried putting a Response.Redirect into this method just to see if anything happens, but nothing does.

Am I suppose to use the login template to get an ID for the username textbox? And how would this be done exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Forms Authentication properly configured, you can call `User.Identity.Name` after you login.

```
Session["accountCustUsername"] = User.Identity.Name;
//if you aren't in your code behind use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

But you really don't need to do that since that value is always available to you as long as you are logged in.

You can put this code in the Page_Load of the TaskPanel.aspx page (since I assume thats the page you arrive at after login)

Comment: Do I need an assembaly refrence? The name User does not appear in the current context.

Comment: Got it: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name ! Why did this work and not your suggestion? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PatrickKeane i thought you were trying to access it from a web page code behind, so i didn't think you'd need to use the fully qualified name.

Comment: @PatrickKeane You probably don't have the using statements for System.Web. Within the context of a code behind file you wouldn't need to use the fully qualified name if the right namespace is imported.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Membership Api functions to get the currently logged in user.

Include this namespace

```
using System.Web.Security;
```

Access the current user

```
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
string username = currentUser.Username;
```

OR

```
string username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```